# Angular two $scope and splice. How to equate one to the other $scope?

Tags: angularjs, scope, splice, equals-operator

The problem is this:

```
$scope.model1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$scope.model2 =  $scope.model1;

$scope.model2.splice(2, 1);

 <pre>{{model1}}</pre>
 <pre>{{model2}}</pre>
```

Return:

```
[1,2,4,5,6,7]
[1,2,4,5,6,7]
```

Need:

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
 [1,2,4,5,6,7]
```

Why is this happening?

**Update:**
solution: <s>Everywhere</s> use **`angular.copy($scope.val)`**
My code is bad:

```
$scope.$watch('checkedImages', function (newVal) {
        if (newVal !== undefined && newVal[0] !== undefined) {
            if ($scope.model.curSupplier === undefined) {
                $scope.model.curSupplier = newVal[0].supplier_id;
                $scope.model.curCheckedImages = newVal;
            }
            $scope.supplier = newVal[0].supplier_id;
        }
    });
```

vs

```
$scope.$watch('checkedImages', function (newVal) {
    if (newVal !== undefined && newVal[0] !== undefined) {
        if ($scope.model.curSupplier === undefined) {
            $scope.model.curSupplier = angular.copy(newVal[0].supplier_id);
            $scope.model.curCheckedImages =  angular.copy(newVal);
        }
        $scope.supplier =  angular.copy(newVal[0].supplier_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `angular.copy` everywhere is not a very good idea. Sometimes you do want the original object to be modified when you change a value in your directive (e.g. if you use a property in an `ng-model`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By assigning one list to another you are simply copying the reference.*

This means that both the models actually refer to the same list. Therefore changing any of them would reflect on the other.

Instead try this:

```
$scope.model2 =  angular.copy($scope.model1);
```

**Update:**

```
$scope.$watch('checkedImages', function (newVal) {
    if (newVal !== undefined && newVal[0] !== undefined) {
        var newObj = angular.copy(newVal);
        if ($scope.model.curSupplier === undefined) {
            $scope.model.curSupplier = newObj[0].supplier_id;
            $scope.model.curCheckedImages =  newObj;
        }
        $scope.supplier =  newObj[0].supplier_id;
    }
});
```

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko if you feel its proper one, you welcome to accept with "V" :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want a *deep copy* or *shallow copy* of the data in the array. For a deep copy, you can use [angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) and for a shallow one-level-deep copy, you can use [array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).